# Consistent string sorting between Java and C#/.NET

Tags: java, c#, sorting, locale, case-insensitive

I have a Java program that emits a list of street names. The names shall be sorted case-insensitively. The consumer is a C#-application which uses the list for a binary search algorithm, so it has to use exactly the same ordering.

The exact kind of sorting isn't very important, though an alphabetically and maybe (German)-locale dependent would be nice.

I failed find a matching pair of 'case insensitive string comparer objects' between the two platforms. The best results I got so far were:

- java: `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`
- .NET: `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

But they disagree on a comparison of 'ü' and 'ß' (see note 1).

More specific locales/cultures (like `DE-de`) differ in handling white spaces and special characters.

Which pair of case-insensitive Comparers/Orders/Collators can I choose for Java and .NET which agree for every single given Unicode-string?

(toLower/toUpper is not an option, for several reasons)

Note 1:
I assume that Java does a toLower before comparing the ordinal value and C# does a toUpper:

```
U+00C4  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS (U+00C4)  Ä
U+00D6  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS (U+00D6)  Ö
U+00DC  LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS (U+00DC)  Ü

U+00DF  LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S (U+00DF)     ß

U+00E4  LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS (U+00E4)    ä
U+00F6  LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS (U+00F6)    ö
U+00FC  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS (U+00FC)    ü
```

Until recently there was no [capital letter for 'ß'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Capital_form), so no implementation uses it yet - and it wouldn't solve the problem above.

Comment: you could *try* `InvariantIgnoreCase` in .NET - worth a go

Comment: `The consumer is a C#-application which uses the list for a binary search algorithm, so it has to use exactly the same ordering.` Could you sort the data again on the C# side to avoid the issue?

Comment: Do you mean `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`? This sorts Umlauts (äöüß) within the latin alphabet whereas Java sorts them to the end. - The line numbers are used as key for look-up-tables in other data structures, so I may not change their order on the receiver's side.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own function at c# side, that goes through every letter. `if` it is an ASCII character then place in the sub-list of ASCII's in it's ordered place. `if` it is a german letter ( I'm pretty sure there is a collection of them ) place them in the UTF sub-list. This results in the defined order ( ASCII's first, äößü... second ).
To do this :

```
List<YourType> temp = new List<YourType>();
int ASCIIcounter = 0;
int UTFcounter = 0;

foreach(YourType inc in yourList)
{
    if (ListASCII.contains(inc.yourSringData))
    { 
        temp.insert(inc, ASCIIcounter); ASCIIcounter++; UTFcounter++;
    }
    else 
    { 
         temp.insert(inc, UTFcounter); UTFcounter++; 
    }
}
temp.sort(0, ASCIIcoutner, null);
temp.sort(ASCIIcounter + 1, UTFcounter, null);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my request for a comparator, nor does it explain how  this matches to any Java implementation. The implementation is exceptionally slow and doesn't explain how `temp.sort` handles case-insensitivity. I have no idea how `ListASCII.contains()` could possibly work on whole strings. What is `YourType`?